# CMake won't pick up Zephyr RTOS related libraries/functionality

Tags: c, cmake, zephyr-rtos

I inherited [a codebase](https://github.com/AnyLedger/anyledger-wallet/), and the author isn't available for questions :/

Whenever I try to compile it:

```
source ~/source/path-to-zephyr/zephyr-env.sh
cd ~/source/path-to-wallet/
mkdir build; cd build; cmake -GNinja -DBOARD=qemu_x86 -DBUILD_XCOMPILE=1 ../

CMake Error at cmake/zephyr.cmake:7 (zephyr_get_include_directories_for_lang_as_string):
  Unknown CMake command "zephyr_get_include_directories_for_lang_as_string".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (include)


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/shinichi/source/wallet/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Why can't CMake find $ZEPHYR_BASE? Surely it knows somehow to find a function called `zephyr_get_include_directories_for_lang_as_string` there, otherwise the compilation instructions would have mentioned some extra needed steps.

So I researched cmake a bit, and thought I'd add this line to wallet/CMakeLists.txt:
`include($ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE}/cmake/extensions.cmake)`

But that just gave me more errors, which points to something more profound not finding the Zephyr RTOS code:

```
...
 get_property could not find TARGET zephyr_interface.  Perhaps it has not
  yet been created.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/shinichi/source/zephyrproject/zephyr/cmake/extensions.cmake:187 (get_property_and_add_prefix)
  /home/shinichi/source/zephyrproject/zephyr/cmake/extensions.cmake:155 (zephyr_get_include_directories_for_lang)
  cmake/zephyr.cmake:7 (zephyr_get_include_directories_for_lang_as_string)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (include)


CMake Error at /home/shinichi/source/zephyrproject/zephyr/cmake/extensions.cmake:301 (get_property):
  get_property could not find TARGET zephyr_interface.  Perhaps it has not
  yet been created.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/shinichi/source/zephyrproject/zephyr/cmake/extensions.cmake:198 (get_property_and_add_prefix)
  /home/shinichi/source/zephyrproject/zephyr/cmake/extensions.cmake:163 (zephyr_get_system_include_directories_for_lang)
  cmake/zephyr.cmake:8 (zephyr_get_system_include_directories_for_lang_as_string)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (include)
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not an ideal solution but I suggest you create and entire new folder and start development from scratch. The zephyr project is relatively new and its tools and environment setup have been changing frequently. As such, the safest solution would be to start from scratch and inherit the delta to the newly setup project if you can. Alternatively, even if you can't work in the newly setup project/folder, doing the separate work might help reveal what the issue is.